# Как настроить IPv6 в vagrant?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant, ipv6

Windows хост, на нем делаю

```
> vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
> vagrant ssh
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (64.233.161.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lh-in-f101.1e100.net (64.233.161.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=24.7 ms
$ ping6 google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
$ ping6 2a00:1450:4010:c01::65
connect: Network is unreachable
$ exit
> ping -6 google.com

Обмен пакетами с google.com [2a00:1450:4010:c01::65] с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 2a00:1450:4010:c01::65: время=25мс
```

Итак, на хосте есть IPv6, на госте нету. Как сделать чтоб было?

Comment: провайдер - виртуалбокс?

Comment: Удалось ли найти ответ? Я сейчас разбираюсь с такой же проблемой...